# Issue with angular UT when having a watch in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a controller like below

```
(function () {
    angular.module("WatchApp", [])
        .controller("WatchController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.options = {
                rowSelection: true
                , multiSelect: false
                , autoSelect: false
                , decapitate: false
                , largeEditDialog: false
                , boundaryLinks: false
                , limitSelect: true
                , pageSelect: true
            };

            $scope.$watch($scope.options.rowSelection, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!oldValue) {
                    console.log("! old Value ");
                }

                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    console.log("newValue != old Value ");
                }

                if (!newValue) {
                    console.log("! newValue");
                }

            });
        });
}());
```

also I have a UT for this controller like below

```
describe("WatchController", function () {
    var $scope;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module("WatchApp");
        return null;
    });
    beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$controller_) {
            $scope = {};
            controller: _$controller_("WatchController", {
                $scope: $scope
            });

        }));
    describe("Initialization", function () {
        it("newPlace.city and country should be empty", function () {
            expect($scope.options.rowSelection).toEqual(true);
        })
    });

});
```

This UT will work fine if I remove the $scope.$watch block, else I am getting the below exception.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) WatchController Initialization newPlace.city and country should be empty F
        TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$scope.$watch') (line 15)
        C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/app/controllers/watchController.js:15:26
        [native code]
        instantiate@C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4680:61
        $controller@C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10130:39
        C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2194:21
        C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/test/controllers/watchControllerSpec.js:10:38
        invoke@C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4665:24
        workFn@C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2965:26
        inject@C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2931:28
        C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/test/controllers/watchControllerSpec.js:8:15
        global code@C:/Robin/Studies/Angularjs/ut/test/controllers/watchControllerSpec.js:1:9
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 14 of 14 (1 FAILED) (0.016 secs / 0.39 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

update the watch line code to be:

```
$scope.$watch('options.rowSelection', function (newValue, oldValue) {
```

more detail take a look on watch example on this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: I understood what u mean. But that one is also throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed by modifying the inject method like

```
inject(function (_$controller_, $rootScope) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller: _$controller_("WatchController", {
                $scope: $scope
            });
```